# Preselect checkboxes in a Vuetify list item group from an array of objects

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am trying to preselect checkboxes in a `v-list-item-group` , but can't for the life of me figure out what `true-value` should be set to in order for it to check the checkbox.

I have also tried changing the value of `true-value` to `column.value`, to no avail.

As opposed to most examples I have found, the model for this `v-list-item-group` is an array of **objects**, as opposed to primitives that seem to be the norm.

In the code snippet example provided (sorry, couldn't manage to make it run in the sandbox), "Column 2" should be preselected.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: () => ({
    defaultColumns: [{
        value: 'column1',
        text: 'Column 1',
      },
      {
        value: 'column2',
        text: 'Column 2',
      },
      {
        value: 'column3',
        text: 'Column 3'
      },
    ],
    selectedColumns: [{
      value: 'column2',
      text: 'Column 2',
    }],
  }),
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vuetify/2.2.13/vuetify.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-list>
      <v-subheader>
        Select columns
      </v-subheader>

      <v-list-item-group v-model="selectedColumns" multiple>
        <v-list-item v-for="column in defaultColumns" :key="column.value" :value="column">
          <template v-slot:default="{ active, toggle }">
            <v-list-item-action>
              <v-checkbox
                :input-value="active"
                :true-value="column"
                color="primary"
                @click="toggle"
              />
            </v-list-item-action>

            <v-list-item-title>
              {{ column.text }}
            </v-list-item-title>
          </template>
        </v-list-item>
      </v-list-item-group>
    </v-list>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: The documentation of the vuetify component sucks. Have you ever got it to work?

Comment: @Niklas Amazingly, yes. After spending a ton of time digging around and finding nothing, I eventually ended up with the method in the answer I just posted. I hope it helps, and that Vuetify improves their documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually got this to work by mapping an object to strings when **getting** a value, and reassembling to an object when **setting** by comparing to the defaults.

Simplified example, as the original code is unfortunately proprietary:

```
selectedColumns: {
  get() {
    // Transform objects into strings as it appears to be the only way we
    // can accurately compare values in `v-list-item-group`
    return this.selectedColumns.map(
      (column) => column.value
    )
  },

  set(value) {
    // Transform back into objects by finding the matching column objects
    // in the default set of columns
    const columns = this.defaultColumns.filter(
      (column) => value.includes(column.value)
    )

    // Do something with `columns`. In my case I'm saving it to a store.
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use v-model into v-checkbox instead of toggle or click, assign a boolean value to v-model and the checkbox will be automatically selected/unselected, as per vuetify docs :

```
<v-checkbox
      v-model="checkbox"
      :label="`Checkbox 1: ${checkbox.toString()}`"
    ></v-checkbox>
.
..
...
<script>
  export default {
    data () {
      return {
        checkbox: true,
        radioGroup: 1,
        switch1: true,
      }
    },
  }
</script>
```

To advise you to find a solution i did this example:

https://codepen.io/emkeythekeyem/pen/XWbjzav

HTML :

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-list>
      <v-subheader>
        Select columns
      </v-subheader>

      <v-list-item-group v-model="selectedColumns" multiple>
        <v-list-item v-for="column in defaultColumns" :key="column.value" :value="column">
          <template v-slot:default="{ active, toggle }">
            <v-list-item-action>
              <v-checkbox
                :input-value="active"
                color="primary"
                v-model="selectedColumns.filter(e => e.value === column.value).length > 0"
              />
            </v-list-item-action>

            <v-list-item-title>
              {{ column.text }}
            </v-list-item-title>
          </template>
        </v-list-item>
      </v-list-item-group>
    </v-list>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Vue

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: () => ({
    defaultColumns: [{
        value: 'column1',
        text: 'Column 1',
      },
      {
        value: 'column2',
        text: 'Column 2',
      },
      {
        value: 'column3',
        text: 'Column 3'
      },
    ],
    selectedColumns: [{
      value: 'column2',
      text: 'Column 2',
    }],
  }),
})
```

Comment: Unfortunately using a non-data attribute in `v-model` will result in:

`vue/valid-v-model: 'v-model' directives require the attribute value which is valid as LHS.`